# How to display nested labels in multiple lines?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, material-ui, javascript-objects

I have tried using the map method like I have seen on my research on how to do this but seems like its not the method to use when I have a structure like below:

```
const stepLabels = [
  { labels1: ['First One'] },
  { labels2: ['Second One', 'second One'] },
  { labels3: ['Third One', 'Third One', 'Third One'] }
];
```

And am using the Material UI Stepper to try to render the step labels below

```
<Stepper alternativeLabel activeStep={2} connector={<StepConnector active completed classes={{ line: classes.connector, active: classes.activeConnector, completed: classes.activeConnector }} />} className={classes.stepper}>
        {steps.map(label => (
          <Step key={label}>
            <StepLabel classes={{ root: classes.stepLabelRoot }}>
              <span>
                { stepLabels.map(item => item.labels)}
              </span>
            </StepLabel>
          </Step>
        ))}
      </Stepper>
```

Trying to get this, where below each node, it will display the label. So below the first node, it will say :

[image]

Below first node will show

```
First One
```

Second One will show twice below the second node

```
Second One
Second One
```

Third One will show three times on the third node

```
Third One
Third One
Third One
```

I have been trying to solve this issue for an hour but cant seem to find the answer to this.

Its really confusing to do this because I do know how to use the map method but this structure is a bit confusing. I have done trial and error and get different errors each time. Like something is not defined, etc.

Comment: What result do you expect in the span element ?

Comment: How do you want the nested array `['Third One', 'Third One', 'Third One']` to show in a step label?

Comment: Hey guys, I have updated the post to show what I mean. Let me know if anything still unclear. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the same property name in all elements of the list if you want to iterate and do something with it. Your code:

```
const stepLabels = [
  { labels1: ['First One'] },
  { labels2: ['Second One', 'second One'] },
  { labels3: ['Third One', 'Third One', 'Third One'] }
];
```

Should be changed to:

```
const stepLabels = [
  { labels: ['First One'] },
  { labels: ['Second One', 'second One'] },
  { labels: ['Third One', 'Third One', 'Third One'] }
];
```

If you want to add a newline, you can add a `br` element:

```
<Stepper alternativeLabel activeStep={2} className={classes.stepper}>
  {stepLabels.map((label) => (
    <Step key={label}>
      <StepLabel classes={{ root: classes.stepLabelRoot }}>
        {label.labels.map((item) => (
          <>
            {item}
            <br />
          </>
        ))}
      </StepLabel>
    </Step>
  ))}
</Stepper>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: is it possible to use the index assuming that there is the 1,2,3 order `label[`labels${index+1}`]`

Comment: @cmgchess The index is the second argument of the map callback: `labels.map((item, i) => labels[\`labels${i+1}\`])`.